# multimap<vector<int> > ,char> how to sort it?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, int, multimap

Here's the code, it can compile, but it can't run, why?:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    typedef multimap<vector< int >, char> mmap;

    mmap foo;
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(15);
    v.push_back(14);
    foo.insert(pair<vector< int >, char> (v, 'b'));
    v.clear();
    v.push_back(15);
    v.push_back(80);
    foo.insert(pair<vector< int >, char> (v, 'c'));
    v.clear();
    v.push_back(9);
    v.push_back(17);
    foo.insert(pair<vector< int >, char> (v, 'a'));
    v.clear();

    mmap::iterator iter;

    for (int i = 0; i < iter->first.size(); ++i) {
        wcout << iter->first[i] << " ";
        for (iter = foo.begin(); iter != foo.end(); ++iter) {
            wcout << iter->second << " ";
        }
        wcout << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

15 80 c

15 14 b

9 17 a

I want to plus the integer,then sort it :
(order the numbers from greatest to least

80+15>15+14>9+17

how to  do that?

Comment: You may provide custom comparator that use sum of elements, is that what you need?

Comment: This code actually gives you output?  It shouldn't since you never set `iter` to a valid iterator.

Comment: [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) is a thing and, conveniently, it can take a custom comparison function.

Comment: You really ought to avoid `using namespace std` - it is a bad habit to get into, and [can silently change the meaning of your program](/q/1452721) when you're not expecting it.  Get used to using the namespace prefix (`std` is intentionally very short), or importing *just the names you need* into the *smallest reasonable scope*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to use a custom compare function/functor to help you with that.

```
struct Compare
{
   bool operator()(std::vector<int> const& lhs, std::vector<int> const& rhs) const
   {
      int sum1 = std::accumulate(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), 0);
      int sum2 = std::accumulate(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), 0);
      return (sum1 > sum2); // Not sum1 < sum2, if I understood your question
   }
};
```

and use:

```
typedef multimap<vector< int >, char, Compare> mmap;
```

You'll also have to fix the code that prints the contents of `foo`.

```
mmap::iterator iter = foo.begin();
for ( ; iter != foo.end(); ++iter )
{
   for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < iter->first.size() ; ++i ) {
      wcout << iter->first[i] << " " ;
   }
   wcout << iter->second << " " ;
   wcout << endl ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You initialized iter in your inner for loop:

`for ( iter = foo.begin() ; iter != foo.end() ; ++iter )`

However, you try to access in the outer for loop where it points to nothing:

`for ( int i = 0 ; i < iter->first.size() ; ++i )`